# Splitting a sentence into different words

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my string and i need to retrieve TX as state and 78681 as zip and usa as country.

'5-D Systems, Inc 1 Chisholm Trail, Suite 3200
Round Rock, TX 78681
USA'

Could any one help to bring this using substring function or any other method?Thank You

Comment: You need to fix your design. Store these data points separately, not in a single "address" column. It's very unlikely everyone is going to right their address in a uniform fashion (it's not going to happen), so you're best hope would be with a machine learning algorithm or a real person.

Comment: This is a particularly complex area of Natural Language Processing; a simple `substring` will not likely account for the vast number of “edge” cases there are in postal addresses. Consider parsing outside SQL Server with a machine learning model/library a la [`libpostal`](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal).

Comment: You have a number of string parsing questions so you have exposure to the functionality available. You also have significant experience in tsql. Make an effort - this is not a free coding-writing service,

Comment: my thought was it is free coding writing service.Never look my experience

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select right(str, 3) as country,
       left(right(str, 9), 5) as zip,
       left(right(str, 12), 5) as state
```

Depending on spaces and newlines, the numbers could be off a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the last three values in the string are state, postcode and country (in order), then you can use an approach to get the last three values, delimited by space - remembering that different countries have different standards for states and postcodes (e.g., VIC 3000 Australia).

Note that the less clean your data, the worse this will be (e.g., more errors).

SQL Server easily finds the first space (e.g., CHARINDEX(' ', yourstring) but has problems finding the *last* ones. I find the easiest way to get the last values with delimiters is to use [REVERSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/reverse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

- First do a REVERSE of the whole address string. Result from above would be 'ASU  18687 XT ,kcoR dnuoR  0023 etiuS ,liarT mlohsihC 1 cnI ,smetsyS D-5'
- LTRIM the string to remove leading (previously trailing) spaces

Now,

- Everything up to the first full space is the country - 'ASU'. Reverse it to get your country - 'USA'
- Remove the first few characters matching the length of the country (e.g., with a STUFF or SUBSTRING) then LTRIM the result to remove leading spaces (there are a lot of spaces etc between 'ASU' and '18687')
- Repeat again for postcode and state.